# if a value is null, then use a default value

Tags: vba

Before I code my own function, is there a built-in function in VBA which allows me to specify a default value if a variable / function return value is null? I know of writing out an if conditional statement, but that's a little lengthy. In other languages I could do either a ternary conditional statement, or (I think in Excel) use a function to specify a default value.

e.g.

```
Dim v as integer
v = DefaultValue(SomeFunction(), 5) ' put 5 in v if SomeFunction returns null
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my own function that I wrote:

```
Public Function DefaultValueIfNull(unknown As Variant, optional defaultValue As Variant) As Variant
    If IsNull(unknown) Then
        DefaultValueIfNull = defaultValue
    Else
        DefaultValueIfNull = unknown
    End If
End Function
```

Which appears to do exactly the same thing as the inbuilt function `Nz(value, valueIfNull)` in Access

Comment: That is correct. You can also make `defaultValue` optional. In my codebase a similar function is called [`NZ`](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Nz-Function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c).

Comment: `NZ` exists in Access, for Excel I declared it myself.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise that each application has its own subset of VBA - updated answer - thanks!

Comment: `NZ` is not a part of VBA, it is a part of the Access object model. All VBA applications have their own exposed object model, but VBA is the same. If you go to the Object Browser and select `VBA` from the dropdown, that will mostly be VBA. The rest is the object model.